# Running rails migration moves indexes around in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The app in question was originally created as a Rails 4 app, and later upgraded to Rails 5.

I will create a rails migration that might look like this:

```
class AddPubliclyVisibleToGcodeMacros < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :gcode_macros, :publicly_visible, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

And when I run it, I expect the schema to have a few lines updated, specifically adding `t.boolean  "publicly_visible", default: false`
 to the `gcode_macros` table.

However, running the migration creates a LOT of changes to my schema, mostly just moving indexes from outside a `create_table` block, into it.

[image]

Im quite confused over whats going on here. This isn't something that happened all of a sudden, I've just been working around it for a while now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that this is just how the schema dumper works in Rails. It takes the schema from the database, absolutely irrelevant from how you created the structure in the first place, whether with migrations or direct sql statements.

So when you create a new migration or change anything in the db a new schema is dumped based on the database.

---

**Edit**

I should add that `schema.rb` is not updated if the db is changed directly with sql statements, that is not through a migration. Only when either

```
rake db:migrate
```

or ...

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

are run is the `schema.rb` file updated.